# go + elastigo panic: runtime error: index out of range

Tags: elasticsearch, go

I'm testing golang with elasticsearch

I'm using the library:
https://github.com/mattbaird/elastigo

My problem is when i run:

```
go run elastigo_postal_code2.go
```

The compiler show something like this:

```
panic: runtime error: index out of range

goroutine 1 [running]:
panic(0x893ce0, 0xc82000a150)
        /opt/go/src/runtime/panic.go:464 +0x3ff
main.main()
        /home/hector/go/elastigo_postal_code2.go:80 +0xa30
exit status 2
```

I'm not sure what this means or how I can fix it!

Someone can help me and tell me I'm doing wrong

```
/*

curl -X PUT "http://localhost:9200/mx2/postal_code/1" -d "
{
    \"cp\"         : \"20000\",
    \"colonia\"    : \"Zona Centro\",
    \"ciudad\"     : \"Aguascalientes\",
    \"delegacion\" : \"Aguascalientes\",
    \"location\": {
        \"lat\": \"22.0074\",
        \"lon\": \"-102.2837\"
    }
}"

curl -X PUT "http://localhost:9200/mx2/postal_code/2" -d "
{
    \"cp\"         : \"20008\",
    \"colonia\"    : \"Delegacion de La Secretaria de Comercio y Fomento Industrial\",
    \"ciudad\"     : \"Aguascalientes\",
    \"delegacion\" : \"Aguascalientes\",
    \"location\": {
        \"lat\": \"22.0074\",
        \"lon\": \"-102.2837\"
    }
}"

*/

package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "flag"
    "log"
    elastigo "github.com/mattbaird/elastigo/lib"
)

var (
    eshost *string = flag.String("host", "localhost", "Elasticsearch Server Host Address")
)


func main() {
    flag.Parse()
    log.SetFlags(log.Ltime | log.Lshortfile)

    c := elastigo.NewConn()
    c.Domain = *eshost

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    searchJson := `{
        "size": 10,
        "query": {
            "match": {
                "all": {
                    "query": "aguascalientes",
                    "operator": "and"
                }
            }
        },
        "sort": [{
            "colonia": {
                "order": "asc",
                "mode": "avg"
            }
        }]
    }`

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    searchresponse, err := c.Search("mx2", "postal_code", nil, searchJson)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("error during search:" + err.Error())
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // try marshalling to ElasticSearchResponse type
    var t ElasticSearchResponse
    bytes, err := searchresponse.Hits.Hits[0].Source.MarshalJSON()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("err calling marshalJson:%v", err)
    }

    json.Unmarshal(bytes, &t)
    log.Printf("Search Found: %s", t)
    c.Flush()

}

func (t *ElasticSearchResponse) String() string {
    b, _ := json.Marshal(t)
    return string(b)
}

// used in test suite, chosen to be similar to the documentation
type ElasticSearchResponse struct {
    Cp         string `json:"cp"`
    Colonia    string `json:"colonia"`
    Ciudad     string `json:"ciudad"`
    Delegacion string `json:"delegacion"`
    Location Location `json:"location"`
}

type Location struct {
    Lat string `json:"lat"`
    Lon string `json:"lon"`
}
```

The code of my scritp is here:

https://gist.github.com/hectorgool/c9e18d7d6324a9ed1a2df92ddcc95c08#file-elastigo_example-go-L80

Answer (score 0):

That's not a compile error, you are getting `panic: runtime error: index out of range`

If the slice `searchresponse.Hits.Hits` has a length of 0, indexing the first element is going to be out of range and panic. You can check for the number of Hits first with `searchresponse.Hits.Len()`.